# Python FTDI LibFT4222.dll Wrapper

Tags: python, spi, ftdi

I'm attempting to build simple SPI driver in python for FTDI FT4222 from scratch. I just want to understand I have the basic principles correct.

I have seen in forums that FTDI doesn't support python for LibFT422...

I have the following working:

- ctypes.windll.LoadLibrary('ftd2xx.dll')
- interact with FT_CreateDeviceInfo List
- FT_GetDeviceInfoDetail
- FT_OpenEx (open by handle)

However, when I try to interact with LibFT4222 I get error code 1000, device not recognized as FT4222...

- ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('LibFT4222.dll')
- FT4222_SPIMaster_Init -> returns error?

What am I doing wrong? Am I not properly linking and instantiating the 2 dlls? Anyone have very simple example of just getting to step of d2xx and LibFT4222 running in python?

Thanks!

Comment: could you provide a minimal reproducable example? Because right now I can only guess that you try to open the device via both dlls at the same time. However, it is commonly "either or". So either open it via ftd2xx.dll and send the low level MPSSE commands or open it exclusively via the higher level libFT4222.

Comment: nvm. just looked into the c++ example and realized that they are really used together. Are you abled to get the c++ example running? if so you should be able to transfer it 1:1 to python using ctypes. There is some filtering in the c++ example ```if(desc == "FT4222" || desc == "FT4222 A")``` which might be missing.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I need to try to double check in c++ I'll let you know how that goes.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.